# Function to choose first valid value from list?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm working on a product spreadsheet that needs to map part numbers to descriptions. The part numbers are stored in two separate sheets, "Part Numbers" (the formally defined number list), and "Custom Components" (parts which have yet to make it to the formal list).

I want to search the first list, but if nothing is found then search the second list. The solution is fairly obvious...

```
=if(isna(vlookup(A3,'Part Numbers'!A:C,2,false)),vlookup(A3,'Custom Components'!A:E,2,false),vlookup(A3,'Part Numbers'!A:C,2,false))
```

... except for that fact that this usually runs the `vlookup` function twice on the very long "Part Numbers" list (17k+ items).

What I want is a function which says "Here's a list of expressions; return the first one that yields a valid value." That way the `vlookup` would only have to be run a single time on the "Part Numbers" list. It would look something like:

```
=firstValid(vlookup(A3,'Part Numbers'!A:C,2,false)),vlookup(A3,'Custom Components'!A:E,2,false))
```

Is there such an animal? (I obviously could define a custom JavaScript function, but that would likely slow things down because of the additional overhead.)

Comment: Thanks, but I can't (proprietary). What do you need to know?

Answer (score 0):

The `iferror()` function is what I need:

> **IFERROR**
>   Returns the first argument if it is not an error value, otherwise returns the second argument if present, or a blank if the second argument is absent.

So, the function should be:

```
=iferror(vlookup(A3,'Part Numbers'!A:C,2,false)),vlookup(A3,'Custom Components'!A:E,2,false))
```